# A problem in complex number

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers

> Let $\alpha=(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,...,\alpha_n)$ and $ 0<\alpha_i<1,i=1,...,n$. Also $\gamma=\frac{1}{m} $ be the least common multiple of the denominators $m_i$ of $\alpha_i $ where $α_i = \frac{k_i}{m_i}, k_i,m_i ∈ \mathbb N.$
>
> Whether for every $\alpha_i \in (0,1)$  all roots $λ$ of the equation:
>
> $$\det\biggr(diag(λ^{m\alpha_1},λ^{m\alpha_2},...,λ^{m\alpha_n}  )-I \biggl)=0$$ where $I$ is identity matrix of size $n$ satisfy $|\arg(λ)| > γ\frac{π}{2}$?

Comment: Where is $x$.?.

Comment: Sorry...this is for another section...